# How to send an email at random times with predefined messages?

Tags: php, email, delay, autohotkey, thunderbird

What I want:

- Email sent at random time and day.
- Email picks one of the messages that I have written in a list and sends it.
- If possible, without my interaction to send the email after I have setup it.
- Re-occuring.

Is there any tool or app that would do this? Outlook has delayed delivery, but I cannot randomize it. I was thinking about coding it myself using authotkey or php, but that would require me either run the program in the background, or I would need to setup the server to execute a php file at certain times.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use case? Sounds like an email spambot.

Comment: I use a combination of [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) and autohotkey to automatically send system status mails to myself. Writing autohotkey code that does this at random is probably easier than searching for a specialised tool.

Comment: What is the purpose of randomness when it comes to system monitoring?

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** *If I wasn't banned from asking questions, I would have first created my own question that was specific to my situation, to then answer it myself with my personal implementation. Thereafter, I would have linked my answer to the OP which he is required to alter slightly for his specific needs.*

I had a similar objective a few weeks ago and implemented a solution for it using autohotkey and blat. The first step of the equation is that you need to figure out how to use blat correctly in conjunction with stunnel. For this purpose, you are advised to refer yourself to [this link](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/blat/message/12685) first.

What I specifically required was that on a daily basis, an email gets sent to me with a pdf-attachment. The email body is to contain a specific text from a text-file. Both the pdf and txt files are in a separate directory and number in the hundreds. In this way, I would be reading a different thing and receive a different attachment on a daily basis for the duration of a year.

Thereafter, I compiled it into an exe and used a schedule tasker for it to be activated on a daily basis. I don't know if it can be done on a random basis though, but I guess you can write your own task scheduler for that using autohotkey.

Beneath is my code which you are required to alter according to your specific needs. It activates stunnel, initializes blat and then sends your emails. If no internet connection is found, it then opens the pdf files on my comp without sending it.

```
global path = "C:\Your_Personal_Directory\Downloads\blat311\full"
SetWorkingDir %path%

global pdf_dir = "\tmp"
global daily_dir = "\temp"
global tirmidhi_dir = "\tirmidhi\txt"
global faqih_dir =  "C:\Your_Personal_Directory\Downloads\Islamic-Books\Faqeehul-Ummat\split"
global thaanwi_dir = "C:\Your_Personal_Directory\Downloads\Islamic-Books\Thaanwi\split"

global pdf = "*.pdf"
global txt = "*.txt"
global docx = "*.docx"
global delim = "\"

global pdf_MaxCount = ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").NameSpace(path . pdf_dir).Items.Count
global tirmidhi_MaxCount = ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").NameSpace(path . tirmidhi_dir).Items.Count
global faqih_MaxCount = ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").NameSpace(faqih_dir).Items.Count
global thaanwi_MaxCount = ComObjCreate("Shell.Application").NameSpace(thaanwi_dir).Items.Count

global max_days = 365
global days := Retrieve_Days()
global custom_days := Retrieve_Days(true)
global ini_file = "daily_email.ini"

acrobat := "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRD32.exe "
stunnel := "C:\Program Files\stunnel\stunnel.exe "

url=www.google.com
internet := true

RunWait, ping.exe %url% -n 1,, hide UseErrorlevel
If Errorlevel
{
    MsgBox, No internet Connection, try again later.
    internet := false
}

Run, %stunnel%,, hide UseErrorlevel
If Errorlevel
{
    MsgBox, Something went wrong with stunnel.
    internet := false
}

Retrieve_Days(custom_year = false) {
    current_date := A_YYYY . A_MM . A_DD
    if !custom_year
        begin_date := A_YYYY . 01 . 01
    else
        begin_date := 2013 . 08 . 17
    EnvSub, current_date, %begin_date%, days 
    If (current_date < 0)
    {
        MsgBox, Current Date yields negative.
        Exit
    }
    return current_date + 1 ; Returns days passed since begin_date
}

Retrieve_File(l_path, sub_dir = "", file_extension_search = "*.*", number = 1) {
    ;Initialize
    FileList = 
    search = %l_path%%sub_dir%\%file_extension_search%

    Loop, %search%
        FileList = %FileList%%A_LoopFileName%`n

    Sort, FileList  ; The R option sorts in reverse order. See Sort for other options.
    Loop, parse, FileList, `n
    {
        if A_LoopField =  ; Ignore the blank item at the end of the list.
            continue
        test = %A_Index%
        if (test = number)
            return l_path . sub_dir . delim . A_LoopField
    }
}

daily := retrieve_file(path, daily_dir, txt, Mod(days, max_days))
pdf_attachment := retrieve_file(path, pdf_dir, pdf, Mod(custom_days, pdf_MaxCount))
tirmidhi := retrieve_file(path, tirmidhi_dir, txt, Mod(custom_days, tirmidhi_MaxCount))
faqih_attachment := retrieve_file(faqih_dir,, pdf, Mod(custom_days, faqih_MaxCount))
thaanwi_attachment := retrieve_file(thaanwi_dir,, pdf, Mod(custom_days, thaanwi_MaxCount))

If internet
{
    runwait blat -install 127.0.0.1 "Your Name <your_email_address@gmail.com>"- - -u your_email_address@gmail.com -pwd Your_Pasword,, hide
    runwait blat %daily% -to your_email_address@gmail.com -subject "Daily Quran Reading" -attach %pdf_attachment%,, hide
    runwait blat %tirmidhi% -to your_email_address@gmail.com -subject "Daily Tirmidhi Reading",, hide
    runwait blat %daily% -to your_email_address@gmail.com -subject "Daily Akaabir Reading: Faqihul-Ummat" -attach %faqih_attachment%,, hide UseErrorlevel
    If Errorlevel
    {
        MsgBox, Something went wrong with faqih_attachment: %faqih_attachment%
        exit
    }

    runwait blat %tirmidhi% -to your_email_address@gmail.com -subject "Daily Akaabir Reading: Thaanwi" -attach %thaanwi_attachment%,, hide UseErrorlevel
    If Errorlevel
    {
        MsgBox, Something went wrong with thaanwi_attachment: %thaanwi_attachment%
        exit
    }

    Run, %stunnel% -exit,, hide UseErrorlevel
    If Errorlevel
    {
        MsgBox, Something went wrong with stunnel.
        exit
    }
}

else
{
    run notepad %daily%
    run notepad %tirmidhi%
    run %acrobat% %pdf_attachment%
    run %acrobat% %faqih_attachment%
    run %acrobat% %thaanwi_attachment%
}
return
```